# Linear Algebra Question for Repeated Eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, multilinear-algebra

Can somebody explain what the sentence in the red circle means?

[image]

Comment: The meaning of the word "redundant" is "unnecessary". Does that answer your question?

Comment: I mean why two of the equations are redundant. Is that because there are two repeated eigenvalues? Then, why two of them are unnecessary?

Answer (score 2):

Intuitively it means that, when combined with the other equations, they provide the same information. More rigorously, it means that there is some "linear combination" of the equations which gives $0=0$.

This is easiest to see when, as in your case, you have $n$ equations and $n-1$ of them are redundant; this means that each one is a scalar multiple of the other.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer to my ignorant question. ^^

Answer (score 2):

Since $\det(A-\lambda I) = 0$, $A-\lambda I$ is singular and therefore not full (row) rank. Therefore some equations can be written into a linear combination of others, and those equations are considered to be "redundant", as they give no additional information about the solutions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer to my ignorant question. ^^

Comment: I think this is a meaningful question, at least in the sense that we can check with whether we can fully understand the concepts learnt before. Through computation of spectral decomposition we always find not all the equations are needed to find an eigenvector, but why it is true as a general phenomenon is a good question to ask by ourselves.

Comment: Allow me one more question here, in spectral decomposition, do we always get repeated eigenvalues? Maybe I am not understand that why repeated eigenvalues are produced. I am studying Linear Algebra, but I don't think I understand deep inside of it yet.

Comment: No we do not. Consider a diagonal matrix with their entries all distinct. Then its spectral decomposition is itself. Repeated eigenvalues may be resulted from that the null space of $A - \lambda I$ has dimension larger than 1, or that there exists vectors $v \neq 0$ such that $(A - \lambda I) v \neq 0$  and $(A - \lambda I)^2 v = 0$.

Comment: Oops, I am lost. $(A−λI)^2v=0$ Haven't seen it yet...

Comment: Those are call generalized eigenvectors. You can google Jordan decomposition for more.

Answer (score 0):

It means that you don't need them to solve the system. The other equations gave you already all the information you needed, thus they are redundant.